# Realtime kernel running as virtual machine

Tags: kernel, windows, virtualization, realtime

I read that using a Linux kernel (Ubuntu rt kernel) was able to increase the response time of a Java application by 4x.

My only problem is that I must run a program that only has a Windows installation on the same machine.

My question is: Will running a rt kernel through a virtual machine on the Windows box completely defeat the purpose of using the rt kernel?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will running a rt kernel through a virtual machine on the windows box completely defeat the purpose of using the rt kernel?

#### Yes.

The VM itself is competing for real CPU time/priority. The RT scheduling will have no major effect.

If you're desperate and you can, flip the problem: Install Ubuntu on bare metal and run Windows in VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Oli.  The windows program interacts with the java program by mouse.  Is WINE an viable idea for running the windows program, will the windows program in wine be able to interact by mouse with the java program running on linux?

Comment: How do you mean by interacting by mouse? The Windows program sends mouse events directly to the java app? That could cause issues with both VM and WINE ideas.

Comment: Not directly, it actually moves the mouse on the screen and clicks like a user would.  I'm thinking of just running some tests.  What version of a linux realtime kernel would you suggest a newbie install as dual boot for now?